# .apk filename changes after doing adb install

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, adb

If I do:

adb install myAppRelease-2012-07-24_14-35-14.apk

When I try to reference the actual .apk file after it is installed

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
for (ApplicationInfo app : pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)) {
    Log.d("PackageList", "package: " + app.packageName + ", sourceDir: " + app.sourceDir);
    String appName = "myAppRelease"
    if(app.packageName.contains("myApp")){
        if(app.sourceDir.contains(appName)){
            apkVersion = app.sourceDir.substring(app.sourceDir.indexOf(appName), app.sourceDir.indexOf(apk));
        }
    }
}
```

What I see is this:

```
07-24 14:46:40.190: D/PackageList(7421): package: myApp, sourceDir: /data/app/myApp-1.apk
```

What I expected to see is this:

```
07-24 14:46:40.190: D/PackageList(7421): package: myApp, sourceDir: /data/app/myAppRelease-2012-07-24_14-35-14.apk
```

It appears that it uses

```
android:label="myApp"
android:versionCode="1"
```

from the manifest file.

My question is, why doesn't it keep the original .apk filename?  I am relying on the .apk filename to display version information for my app.

Comment: Are you sure that it uses the label and version code from the Manifest? That is, have you tried some other names and gotten a reliable result?

Comment: "I am relying on the .apk filename to display version information for my app" -- please use the `android:versionName` attribute of the `<manifest>` element to "display version information for [your] app". You can get this information from `PackageManager`.

Comment: We have an autobuild system that creates the .apk files with the version information in the filename.  We are trying to avoid updating `android:versinName` every time we make a change to the app.

Comment: testing out the label and versionCode changes now.

Comment: Perhaps you can use versionCode instead of versionName with your build system. versionCode will be entirely invisible to your end users.  As CommonsWare states, PackageManager.getPackageInfo() can get both versionName & versionCode.

Comment: "We are trying to avoid updating android:versinName every time we make a change to the app" -- sorry, but that is your only real choice. First, it is what the user will want, since that version information is what they use when they obtain your app (e.g., Play Store) or examine your app (e.g., Settings). Second, the on-device filename could be anything -- relying upon it staying the same across all devices and OS version is unwise.

Comment: Is there another option that will auto increment with the latest code and our latest build from our auto build system (jenkins in this case)?  There is no way to sync the two.

Comment: By the way it does not seem to use `label` and `versionCode` like I thought, I just assumed that and I was wrong.  After chaning both, it still showed `myApp-1.apk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on this, and it definitely doesn't use the version code for the number after the '-'. Especially with newer versions, apps can be moved to the SD card, or forward locked (aka, 'app encryption'), so the actual file on disk can be very different from the original file.

Use `PackageManager` to get version info, that is guaranteed to be correct and up to date. Change your build system to update the version code and maybe display it in an About dialog or similar so it is easy for users to report it.